# Django, applications with fixtures

Tags: python, django, django-fixtures

I am writing Django app, it is an admin interface based on jQuery Grid Plugin. Now i want to make demo of this app and to allow experiments with different data, and of course just to test it. Do you guys know any django applications with predefined fixtures? i've found [django-countries](http://code.google.com/p/django-countries/), which goes with country list. But i would like to find more. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, sorry, my english is not perfect)

Comment: You don't need to apologize.  Very few people have perfect English.  However, what you did was update the question; that's what's important.  The comment, however, isn't really very meaningful.  Just updating the question is all that's needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[djangoembed](https://github.com/worldcompany/djangoembed) and [django-oembed](https://github.com/ericflo/django-oembed) both contain fixture data for the set of OEmbed providers.